# Python format() Function KeyError

Tags: python

I'm new Python and getting a KeyError trying to use the format() function:

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are { age } years old".format( age )

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
```

Error:

```
KeyError: ' age '
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a a named placeholder in the format string, you need to provide named arguments.

And you shouldn't have spaces around the name in the placeholder.

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are {age} years old".format(age=age)
```

Comment: Barmar, I tried your suggestion but still get the same exact result, KeyError: ' age '. What's wrong with it? I want to use this approach instead of f-strings.

Comment: Get rid of the spaces in `{ age }`

Comment: Same result: KeyError: ' age ' Please check your code. I'll accept your answer when it runs.

Comment: I tested this, I don't get that error. You only get the error with the spaces.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, it DOES work. My server had disconnected. This was the answer I was looking for. Thank you for not using f-strings.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a modern f string approach.

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return f'Hello, {name} you are {age} years old.'
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the original code didn't work.

Comment: @Barmar - you are **right**. But the original code is a mix of string concatenation using + and format so it looked to me it needs a different approach.

Comment: It looks like he's using `.format()` for `age` because it's an `int` rather than a string, so it can't be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word 'age' in between the curly brackets. As such

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are {} years old".format( age )

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use f strings.

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return (f'Hello, {name} you are {age} years old.')

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
print(sentence1)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it shows a completely different way to do the same thing.

Comment: Fair enough, however, I feel like f strings are more pythonic overall, not to mention easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `f-strings`: they allow you to format directly in your string. Do notice that you have to put an `f` before the quotation marks.

```
print(f"Hello {name} you are {age} years old")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format your text and fill a string with some variables, you can put them in format method "in your desired" order.
if there is just one variable, you can change your code to this:

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are {} years old".format(age)

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
```

Also this one works:

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are {age} years old".format(age=age)

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
```

In some cases, you maybe want to have multiple variables. You can use second method to your code be more readable.

Also using `f-string` is on the table (recommended). like this:

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return f"Hello, {name} you are {age} years old"

sentence1 = hello('Mark', 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove a space and pass age variable to format

```
"you are {age} years old".format(age=age)

def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are {age} years old".format(age=age)

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use .format, the curly brakets has to be empty:

```
def hello( name="Sean", age=0 ):
    return 'Hello, ' + name + " you are {} years old".format(age)

sentence1 = hello( 'Mark', 17 )
```

You sould consider using f"" as so:

```
return f'Hello, {name} you are {age} years old'
```

This way you can directly put variables in your string